Sitecore Content Serialization only One Template
I am trying to do serialize the Template Field template. I added a new field on that template. The path is /sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template field. I created a Templates.Module.json file.
The code below will get all the templates (everything) under Templates folder, which I don't want. I just need the Template Field template which is under the Templates folder. How can I get that?
{  
  "namespace": "Foundation.Template",  
  "items": {
    "includes": [
       {
         "name": "templates",
         "path": "/sitecore/templates/System/Templates"
       }
    ]  
  }
}


Target that specific item by specifying it in the path:
{
  "namespace": "Foundation.Template",
  "items": {
    "includes": [
      {
        "name": "templateField",
        "path": "/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template field"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Also consider using the scope parameter as needed, which has the following valid options:
SingleItem, ItemAndChildren, ItemAndDescendants, and DescendantsOnly, with the default value being ItemAndDescendants.
Source:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/developer-tools/sitecore-content-serialization-configuration-reference.html#scope
